# Why most kernels do not support other than 640x400 resolution?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, display-resolution, xrandr, nouveau

```
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-74-generic x86_64
SourcePackage: linux-signed-hwe
```

I have a notebook with an Nvidia G102M, and till kernel 4.15.0-74 the video driver work well at native screen resolution of 1368x768 @ 60.00 Hz, while all the subsequent kernels start in 640x400 from the display manager/login screen, and seems do not support any other resolution.

Kernels are not working: `4.15.0-88, 5.0.0-37, 5.3.0-28, 5.3.0-40`

For each kernel KV I have the following packages:

```
linux-headers-KV
linux-headers-KV-generic
linux-image-KV-generic
linux-modules-KV-generic
linux-modules-extra-KV-generic
```

More I have the following packages installed:

```
xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04
```

And neither of the following is installed:

```
linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-modules-nvidia-430-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-modules-nvidia-435-generic-hwe-18.04
linux-modules-nvidia-390-KV-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-430-KV-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-435-KV-generic
```

With KV 4.15.0-74 I got:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*LVDS-1 1366/344x768/194+0+0 LVDS-1
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768 59.97*+
...
```

With the other kernels, any trial to set the same native resolution 1366 x 768 fails

Comment: Can you please clarify what KV is.  I don't see reference to it in official Ubuntu repositories (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-kernel-KV&searchon=names), and if it's 3rd party why not provide your source.  Or if you're using it as a standard in as *kernel.version* you maybe should have said so.

Comment: @guiverc KVM probably. Kernel Virtual Machine.

Comment: I suspected that myself, but it wasn't just a single typo but KV every time...

Comment: KV is Kernel Version